# PhantomJS clickable hyperlink in PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, phantomjs

**Research done:** 
The last time I was able to find this question asked was back in 2014 and I can't seem to find anything more recent. I am exporting a PDF and it has several hyperlinks which are not clickable. Everything I can find says this was addressed and shouldn't be an issue. I'm running 2.1.1 and simply calling the render method.

**Actual Question**
Are clickable hyperlinks supported in PhantomJS PDF output and if so what is the option I need to set?

**Code Sample:**

I can post a code snippet but its really a basic usage of:

```
page.open(address, function(status) { 
     // bla bla 
     page.render(output, {quality: 100});
}
```